Primevue FileUpload custom error handling
For a project I'm using the PrimeVue  component.
Since I'm dutch and the app will be in Dutch as well, I would like to catch the "file size too large" error and replace it with a Toast message.
However, I'm stuck with how to catch that error. I've tried to use the following:
<FileUpload 
     chooseLabel="Selecteer foto" 
     mode="basic" 
     @error="onFileError"
     @select="onFileSelect" 
     customUpload 
     accept="image/*" 
    :maxFileSize="1000000"
     severity="secondary" 
    :multiple="false"
 /> 

However, either the '@error' is not a valid option, or the filesize error is not triggering the @error option.
So I'm a bit stuck with how to catch that error...
my setup snippet:
"primevue": "^4.0.4",
"vue": "^3.4.29",
"tailwindcss": "^3.4.10",
"tailwindcss-primeui": "^0.3.4"**
thank you in advance!

You can use @before-upload to handle your case there. here is the primevue link

PrimeVue FileUpload component custom maxFileSize handler

Use the @select="onUploadFileSelection" event, in there you can process the files yourself, e.g.:
  const onUploadFileSelection = (event: FileUploadSelectEvent): void => {
      const file: File = Array.isArray(event?.files)
        ? event?.files?.findLast((f: File): boolean => !!f?.size)
        : event?.files; // To have the most recent uploaded file

      if (file) {
        // Your allowed mime types
        const typeIndex = ALLOWED_MIME_TYPES.findIndex((uploadType: string) => uploadType === file.type);
        if (typeIndex >= 0) {
          /// Your file size
          if (file.size > TWENTY_MB_IN_BYTES) {
            // Report size error
          } else {
             // Do upload + error handling from your back-end
          }    
        } else {
          // Report type error
        }
      }
  };



Thats not working. MaxFileSize will be remove file before FileUpload component call select hook.

you can use before-upload event as mentioned in primevue documentation.
In template:-
 <FileUpload
  chooseLabel="Selecteer foto"
  mode="basic"
  @before-upload="onBeforeUpload"
  @select="onFileSelect"
  customUpload
  accept="image/*"
  :maxFileSize="1000000"
  severity="secondary"
  :multiple="false"
/>

In script:-
onBeforeUpload(event) {
  const file = event.files[0];
  const maxFileSize = 1000000; // 1MB

  if (file.size > maxFileSize) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    this.toast.add({
      severity: "error",
      summary: "Test",
      detail: "Test",
      life: 3000,
    });
  }
},

Here is the codesandbox link.

Thats not working. MaxFileSize will be remove file before FileUpload component call before-update hook.
